# Can I use Python 3 for one Mac user, and Python 2 for another user?

Tags: python, macos

My job uses Python 3, but for school I use Python 2. When installing other programs on a Mac, you can decide whether you want to install the application for just one user or all users. I was wondering if you could also do this with a Mac? I have a personal account, and a work account already set up, and it would be great if I could just have Python 3 on the work account and Python 2 on the personal account.

Comment: You can run multiple versions within a single user account - by default they'll be `python` and `python3` in the terminal, and you can use `virtualenv`s to control a specific interpreter per project.

Comment: Pyenv https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial is well suited for this :)